# Understanding Roles in Rails 3.2 with Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, roles, cancan

Is there any easy tutorial for roles? I found that [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is great & easy solution for authorization. And then when it comes to [Cancan with Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify/wiki/Tutorial) there's a confusion eclipse for beginners like me.

Currently I'm defining roles in **ability.rb**:

```
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :read, :all
end
```

And then, in the controller, I'm checking like in this example:

```
def destroy
 ability = Ability.new(current_user)
 if ability.can? :delete, :all then
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @post.destroy
 end

 respond_to do |format|
   ...
end
```

My question is - I have a strange feeling the check **if ability.can? :delete, :all then** is redundant in this example. So is my code ok or I really got it wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to check if they can delete the post in question. An admin may be able to delete anything, but a normal user would only delete content they own.

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
authorize! :delete, @post
```

I'd also suggest you spend some time reading cancan's documentation, as your code doesn't really match up.

Comment: @DVG But how can valk integrate Rolify with CanCan?

Answer (score 0):

I think your "destroy" method can be like:

```
def destroy
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 if can? :delete, @post then 
   @post.destroy
 end

 respond_to do |format|
   ...
end
```

Because in [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)'s doc:

> The current user’s permissions can then be checked using the can? and
>   cannot? methods in the view and controller.